# DevExpress Silverlight Chart CustomPalette

Tags: silverlight, devexpress

When I instantiate a DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.CustomPalette, I cannot find how to set my own Colors in code.  The constructor takes no parameters, and the Colors property is Read-Only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic. The [Colors](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#Silverlight/DevExpressXpfChartsCustomPalette_Colorstopic) property is a colection (`System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<System.Windows.Media.Color>`). Thus you should **add** your colors into this colection:

```
CustomPalette palette = new CustomPalette();
//...
palette.Colors.Add(Colors.Green);
//...
```